# CSS Click Event

Tags: css

can u help me to fix the following (In CSS Language), why my Click Event doesn't work! also how i can copy a specific text, let's say when it's clicked i want to copy "Hello" Here is my code: (Thanks in advance)

```
<head><style>.button {onclick="myFunction()"; background-color: #4CAF50; border: none; color: white; padding: 8px 15px; text-align: center; text-decoration: bold; display: inline-block; font-size: 16px; margin: 4px 2px; cursor: pointer;} </style></head><button class="button">Copy</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  alert("Copied the text: ");
}
</script>
```

Comment: Wait, what's this code? What language is this?

Comment: It's CSS langauge

Comment: Umm... I am a CSS Expert. I haven't seen a syntax like this. Where did you find this? Or is it **not** Cascading Style Sheets?

Comment: I'm learning new stuff on "w3schools" site visit this https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_buttons_basic

Comment: Click event and copying text will be in JavaScript, and you can't do with CSS. And the syntax you have written is completely invalid.

Comment: But there's nothing like onclick being given in the style tag right?

Comment: @PraveenKumar i want to send an email with button in c# so i knew how to add a button and it worked but how to copy? (Html body)

Comment: Onclick is not css property. If you like to style specific button that call a function set it ID. I think you should rewrite the question.

Comment: @AhmadEgbaria Wait. We are talking four things here. **1.** Styling of the button. (CSS) **2.** Assigning an event handler (basic JavaScript) **3.** Copying contents to the clipboard. (Advanced JavaScript). **4.** Sending email - AJAX / Server side. Are you aware of these things are involved in what you are talking?

Comment: @PraveenKumar all of i want here is to know why click event doesn't work

Comment: @AhmadEgbaria Because the syntax for click event is [`click`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/click) and not what you have written.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
 document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var copyText = document.getElementById('copy-text');
  document.getElementById('copy-button').addEventListener('click', function() {
    copyText.select();
    document.execCommand('copy');
  });
});
```

```css
.button {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 8px 15px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: bold;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 4px 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<input id="copy-text" value="Hello" />
<button id="copy-button" class="button">Copy</button>
```